# Error deploying webservice on weblogic: cannot cast to com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingProvider

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy a web-service in weblogic and I get the following errors:

```
    weblogic.management.DeploymentException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: Fallo al analizar el descriptor en tiempo de ejecución: com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingProvider: Provider weblogic.wsee.databinding.internal.wlsjaxrpc.JaxRpcProvider is specified in jar:file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.webservices.wls.wls-ws-metainf-services-impl_12.1.3.jar!/META-INF/services/com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingProviderbut could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast weblogic.wsee.databinding.internal.wlsjaxrpc.JaxRpcProvider to com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingProvider

com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: Fallo al analizar el descriptor en tiempo de ejecución: com.sun.xml.ws.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingProvider: Provider weblogic.wsee.databinding.internal.wlsjaxrpc.JaxRpcProvider is specified in jar:file:/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oracle_common/modules/com.oracle.webservices.wls.wls-ws-metainf-services-impl_12.1.3.jar!/META-INF/services/com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingProviderbut could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast weblogic.wsee.databinding.internal.wlsjaxrpc.JaxRpcProvider to com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingProvider
```

What am I doing wrong? I used jaxws-rt for my webservice
java web-services weblogic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem of clashing classes, the ones you ship in your deployment and the ones provided by WebLogic, as the error message is telling you:

```
Cannot cast weblogic.wsee.databinding.internal.wlsjaxrpc.JaxRpcProvider to com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingProvider
```

Set a filter in your `web.xml` to tell your application to [prefer its own resources](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#i1075205).

Comment: I added that property in the weblogic.xml configuration file: <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>